# HT630 JobGen - Insert 0 if collect data is empty

Tags: c

I'm programming a Unitech HT630 terminal with JobGen Plus. It's possible to write C code that will execute on certain events.

Users have 4 fields to fill in. Users are suppose to either scan, use the keyboard or just press (ENT). That's where the tricky part comes. When the user just presses (ENT) without entering any data the field must be set to string value "0".

Is there anyone with some experience of JobGen that can help me?

Best regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your collect node is named "collect1". If user just presses ENT, then on the next program node state _collect1 = 0;

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a new Collect node after your Collect Node and change the value to 0 if there is no data entered.

Eg: If the Collect node is "collect1" then create a new node eg: result1 and do the changes as below

Input -> Initial Value -> Set New Value -> By Formula and use the C code below

```
if(strlen(_collect1)==0)
{
   strcpy(_collect1,"0");
}
```

When you write the data record to a file the value will be 0 if there is no data entered